# libstdc++ invalid free a std::string

Tags: c++11, gcc, libstdc++

gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) run my code will coredump. valgrind message is :

```
==14892== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()

==14892==    at 0x4C2B343: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:502)

==14892==    by 0x53404DE: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)

==14892==    by 0x5AE2258: __run_exit_handlers (exit.c:82)

==14892==    by 0x5AE22A4: exit (exit.c:104)

==14892==    by 0x5AC7ECB: (below main) (libc-start.c:321)

==14892==  Address 0x55892e8 is in the BSS segment of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
```

when i use gcc version 4.7.2 20121015 (Red Hat 4.7.2-5) (GCC), it won't coredump.

EDIT:

yesterday, i found out the bug of my codes. such as:

`static array[1024][4];
array[1023][4] = '\0'; // this destroy other object`

after i changed this code, it runs well.

Comment: "is this a bug of gcc?" It is much more likely to be a bug in your code.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of source code that causes the issue?

Answer (score 3):

On the balance of probabilities, no, it's *far* more likely to be a bug in your *own* code. There are countless millions of developers "testing" `gcc` every day whereas you code has probably been tested by, well, just you :-)

The most likely explanation is that you're invoking undefined behaviour that just happens to "work" on one of the platforms, though that in no way makes it a good idea.

If you were to provide the code, we could be a lot more definitive. Without that, I'm afraid, generalities are the best we can do.

---

One thing you *may* want to look at, though it may not be fruitful. If that address on the last line of your `valgrind` output is the address being freed, it's a potential worry that it's in the BSS, which is generally used for statically defined variables, not the memory arenas used for dynamic allocation.

Still, that's *very* dependent on the implementation, hence why I'm including it as an aside.

The core answer remains the likelihood of a problem (of *some* description) in your own code.

---

And, based on your later comment that you have code like:

```
static char array[1024][4];
array[1023][4] = 0;
```

that is *indeed* a bug.

That definition gives you an array of elements that you can validly access as:

```
array[0..1023][0..3]
```

Using an array index outside of that range is considered undefined behaviour, which may well corrupt some other piece of information, such as a pointer to heap memory that you will later try to free.

Comment: yes. it's bug of my own code.  `static char array[1024][4]; array[1023][4] = 0;` ,  `array[1023][4]` destroy other object.